# Load data in bulk into cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Lets say I have significant amount of data in excel.
I want to **load in cassandra column family**?

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for SQL*Loader like thing (bulk loader), then cassandra has **sstableloader**.

You can know more about **sstableloader** from [here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/references/bulkloader)

Comment: @SaurabhDeshpande if this answers your question, you should "accept" it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the CqlSh [COPY](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/cql_cli/cql/COPY#cqlsh-copy-to-from) command as well. If you can export your excel file to a CSV, you may be able to use the copy command to load it into Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra provides `sstableloader` for loading CSV data into cassandra. By using this `sstabler`, you can load the bulk data into cassandra.
You can know more about sstableloader from the following link.

[ramuprograms.blogspot.in/2014/07/bulk-loading-data-into-cassandra-using.html](http://ramuprograms.blogspot.in/2014/07/bulk-loading-data-into-cassandra-using.html)